# java applet: How to invoke/access javascript variable of web page from applet?

Tags: java, applet

An example:

```
getAppletContext().showDocument(
  new URL("javascript:alert(document.getElementById('textbox').value);"
));
```

Instead of alerting this textbox value, I want to use this value further as string variable in my applet program. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiple ideas for different approaches. Here are some:

---

**Put the input-field in the Applet.** Instead of adding an `<input>`-tag to the HTML-page, you can get input in the Applet by adding AWT components (or, when using a `JApplet` you can use the newer Swing toolkit) to it. Although Swing should be preferred.

Of course, if you can't change the applet-code, this is not an option.

---

**Use the `<param>`-tag.** You can give your applet some initial values (e.g. parameters), by using the `<param>`-tag in the `<applet>`-tag as shown by this example from the [tag-doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/misc/applet.html):

```
<applet code="A21" width="256" height="256" archive="toir.jar">
  <param name="img" value="test.gif">
</applet>
```

However, as I said, these are *initial* values. If you change them while the applet is already running, they won't change in the Applet itself.

So, if the values in your `<input>`-tag are for initial values, you can use this (and manipulate the `value`-attribute with JS). If you want to change the values while the applet is running, this only works if you restart the applet (which might not be the best idea).

---

**Use "Java-to-Javascript Communication".** There is a certain document introducing the `JSObject`-class. It can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html). There is also the "Common DOM API" which can be used to access the DOM-structure of the HTML-page. It sounds like what you're searching for, but it seems a little outdated.

Als, this seems to be no standard (just like the `<applet>`-tag) and therefor, some browsers might not or not completely implement support for that. You'll have to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
// provide a JS function to return the value of textbox
// call it to get the value..
String userInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, value, ..
```

Comment: Andrewthompson: Let's say I have a JS function in my jsp page  which is returning me a textbox value. Now, how to call this JS function from applet to grab the JS function return value. can you please explain?

As i posted an example code in my question.. I am only able to alert it's value.

Comment: *"posted an example code"*  I would describe that as an 'uncompilabe code snippet'.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).